# Kotlin mutableMap automatically changing in android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm setting kotlin mutable map in my viewModel like this,

```
// In ViewModel
var mapData= mutableMapOf<Int, String>()
```

in my fragment i'm referring this map as below,

```
//In fragment
lateinit var _mapData: MutableMap<Int, String>

// in oncreate View
_mapData[1] = "one"
```

When i run above code, this `_mapData` is automatically updated to my viewModel `mapData`. I don't want that,

Where I'm having real problem is in the below code,

```
// initiallizing 
if(!_mapData.contains(2)){
_mapData[2] = _mapData[1]
}

//doing some process to get the actual _mapData[2]

_mapData[2] = "Two"
```

After running the above code my `_mapData[1]` is also changing to `"Two"`.

What is this behaviour and why is it happening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how you assign `_mapData` from `mapData`, but if you simply write:

```
_mapData = viewModel.mapData
```

then both variables store reference to the same exact map object. Thus, if you change anything via `mapData` reference, `_mapData` content will also change (because it's the same object).

If you want to have separate entities of map in viewModel and fragment, you should copy the map:

```
_mapData = viewModel.mapData.toMutableMap()
```